# Is it valid to fold MIME headers at the beginning of field-body?

Tags: mime, folding, rfc822

I'm debugging a MIME parser that fails to parse a header from one email service.  The email service includes a header that consists of a field body entirely on the next line, like so:

```
Message-Id:
  <12345.67890.abcdef@example.com>
```

Is this legal?

RFC-822 specifies the following grammar for valid headers:

```
3.2.  HEADER FIELD DEFINITIONS

      These rules show a field meta-syntax, without regard for the
 particular  type  or internal syntax.  Their purpose is to permit
 detection of fields; also, they present to  higher-level  parsers
 an image of each field as fitting on one line.

 field       =  field-name ":" [ field-body ] CRLF

 field-name  =  1*<any CHAR, excluding CTLs, SPACE, and ":">

 field-body  =  field-body-contents
                [CRLF LWSP-char field-body]

 field-body-contents =
               <the ASCII characters making up the field-body, as
                defined in the following sections, and consisting
                of combinations of atom, quoted-string, and
                specials tokens, or else consisting of texts>
```

Does the empty string satisfy field-body-contents to allow for the `[CRLF LWSP field-body]` portion of field-body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly permissble to fold on whitespace.  Usually, this is only done when the line is otherwise too long, but it is entirely optional anyway; there is no requirement to fold, or to avoid folding.  (Of course, if a line is too long to meet the RFC5321, it *has* to be folded, or somehow otherwise shortened. These days, RFC2047 is somewhat more versatile and transparent than traditional whitespace folding.)

As explained in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3 a folded line is one "logical line".  (Note that ye olde 822 has long been superseded by newer standards; 5322 is the current replacement.)